# Two Handled Items use the same command in e4,one is triggerd,another isnot

Tags: java, eclipse, command, menuitem, e4

I met one issue:

That is:

I added a "Command" named "saveCommand" in e4xmi;

I added a "Handled Menu Item" named "save" use "saveCommand" in e4xmi;

I added a "Handled Tool Item" named "save" use "saveCommand" in e4xmi;

In "saveCommand" it use a "saveHandler" to control the two save buttons actions:
The code is :

```
@CanExecute
public boolean canExecute() {

    if (caseNameValidatePass) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

But now the issue is:
 When canExecute function returns true, the save menu button is enabled, 
 but the save tool button is still disabled.

It confused me.Why?Can somebody help to answer my confusing?Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

`@CanExecute` is called for a menu item each time the menu is displayed, but for a tool item you probably need to request that it is run using the `UIEvents.REQUEST_ENABLEMENT_UPDATE_TOPIC` event:

```
@Inject 
IEventBroker eventBroker;

eventBroker.send(UIEvents.REQUEST_ENABLEMENT_UPDATE_TOPIC, selector);
```

`selector` can be `UIEvents.ALL_ELEMENT_ID` to update all tool items or an implementaton of `org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.Selector` to select particular items to be updated.

You will need to call this whenever your `caseNameValidatePass` value changes.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, it seems a good way to fix that issue.Will have a try today.Thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks greg very much!It's quite useful!